# How to make anchor tag clickable without text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a personal website with links to social media through the corresponding icons. However the link is not clickable.

Here is a JSFiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mufeeza/v9s7psf2/

```
<div class="linkedin icon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mufeezamjad/" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="github icon"><a href="https://www.github.com/mufeez-amjad" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="instagram icon"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/mufeez.a" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="twitter icon"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/mufeeza_" target="_blank"></a></div>


.icon {
    background-color: #363636;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.icon a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.facebook {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgdmlld0JveD0iLTAuNyAtMC42IDEzNCAyNzgiPjxzdHlsZT4uc3R5bGUwe2ZpbGw6CSNGRkZGRkY7fTwvc3R5bGU+PHBhdGggZD0iTTgyLjYgNThjMCAwLTAuNy01LjUgNC40LTkuNmM1LjEtNCA5LjktMy43IDkuOS0zLjdjMTIuOS0xLjYgMjkuOCAyLjYgMjkuOCAyLjZsNS45LTQyLjdjMCAwLTU5LjctMTQuMy04NS45IDcuMkMyOS41IDI0LjUgMjkuMyA0My43IDI5LjMgNDMuN3Y0Ny43SDAuMmwtMC4yIDQyaDI5LjRsLTEuMSAxNDMuMWw1Mi44IDAuM2wwLjMtMTQzLjRoNDMuMWwyLjktNDEuOWwtNDUuMS0wLjJMODIuNiA1OHoiIGNsYXNzPSJzdHlsZTAiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
    background-size: 25%;
}
.facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3664A2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want the entire div around `a` to be clickable, use `display:inline-block`

```
.icon a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do the following change to the CSS by adding `display:block`

```
.icon a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `:before` pseudo element, `content` property set to `attr()` function with parameter set to a `data-*` attribute set at HTML

```
<div class="linkedin icon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mufeezamjad/" target="_blank" data-link="linkedin"></a></div>
<div class="github icon"><a href="https://www.github.com/mufeez-amjad" target="_blank" data-link="github"></a></div>
<div class="instagram icon"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/mufeez.a" target="_blank" data-link="instagram"></a></div>
<div class="twitter icon"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/mufeeza_" target="_blank" data-link="twitter"></a></div>
```

```
a:before {
  content:attr(data-link);
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/99ksjh9g/

Using CSS `:before` pseudo element with `content` set to `url()` function with `data URL` passed as parameter

```css
.icon {
  background-color: #363636;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.icon a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: block;
}

.facebook a:before {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #3664A2;
}

.twitter a:before,
.linkedin a:before,
.instagram a:before,
.github a:before,
.facebook a:before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(.5, .5);
}

.twitter a:before {
  top: -10px;
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld0JveD0iLTAuNyAtMC40IDE4NCAyNDUiID48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjRkZGRkZGIiBkPSJNMTgyLjcsMjEzLjVjMCw4LjQtMywxNS42LTksMjEuNWMtNiw2LTEzLjIsOS0yMS42LDlIOTEuNWMtMjUuMiwwLTQ2LjgtOC45LTY0LjctMjYuOEM4LjksMTk5LjQsMCwxNzcuOSwwLDE1Mi44VjMwLjVjMC04LjYsMy0xNS45LDguOS0yMS43QzE0LjksMi45LDIyLjIsMCwzMC44LDBjOC4zLDAsMTUuNSwzLDIxLjUsOWM2LDYsOSwxMy4xLDksMjEuNXY0NC4zaDg2LjJjNy44LDAsMTQuNSwyLjgsMjAuMSw4LjNjNS42LDUuNSw4LjQsMTIuMiw4LjQsMjBjMCw3LjgtMi44LDE0LjQtOC40LDIwYy01LjYsNS41LTEyLjMsOC4zLTIwLDguM0g2MS4ydjIxLjRjMCw4LjQsMi45LDE1LjUsOC44LDIxLjRjNS45LDUuOSwxMyw4LjgsMjEuNSw4LjhIMTUyYzguNCwwLDE1LjYsMywyMS42LDlDMTc5LjcsMTk4LDE4Mi43LDIwNS4xLDE4Mi43LDIxMy41eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
}

.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #44C8F5;
}

.linkedin a:before {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAtMC4zIDEwNSAxMDUiPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNGRkZGRkYiIGQ9Ik0xLjcsMzQuNmgyMS43djY5LjdIMS43VjM0LjZ6IE0xMi42LDBjNi45LDAsMTIuNiw1LjYsMTIuNiwxMi42YzAsNi45LTUuNiwxMi42LTEyLjYsMTIuNkM1LjYsMjUuMSwwLDE5LjUsMCwxMi42QzAsNS42LDUuNiwwLDEyLjYsMCIvPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNGRkZGRkYiIGQ9Ik0zNywzNC42aDIwLjh2OS41aDAuM2MyLjktNS41LDEwLTExLjMsMjAuNS0xMS4zYzIxLjksMCwyNiwxNC40LDI2LDMzLjJ2MzguMkg4Mi45VjcwLjRjMC04LjEtMC4yLTE4LjUtMTEuMy0xOC41Yy0xMS4zLDAtMTMsOC44LTEzLDE3Ljl2MzQuNUgzN1YzNC42eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
}

.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007BB6;
}

.instagram a:before {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.instagram:hover {
  background-color: #3F729B;
}

.github a:before {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.github:hover {
  background-color: #6CC644;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkedin icon">
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mufeezamjad/" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div class="github icon">
  <a href="https://www.github.com/mufeez-amjad" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram icon">
  <a href="http://www.instagram.com/mufeez.a" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div class="twitter icon">
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mufeeza_" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/99ksjh9g/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.icon a` so that it fills it's parent div.

```css
.icon {
  background-color: #363636;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.icon a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.facebook {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 25%;
}

.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #3664A2;
}

.twitter {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 40%;
}

.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #44C8F5;
}

.linkedin {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 50%;
}

.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007BB6;
}

.instagram {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 55%;
}

.instagram:hover {
  background-color: #3F729B;
}

.github {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 60%;
}

.github:hover {
  background-color: #6CC644;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkedin icon">
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mufeezamjad/" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div class="github icon">
  <a href="https://www.github.com/mufeez-amjad" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram icon">
  <a href="http://www.instagram.com/mufeez.a" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div class="twitter icon">
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mufeeza_" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```